# Calculating all possible lat & long

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, oracle-spatial

I am new to GIA domain. I am trying to learn new concepts around mapping etc and this is my first app/implementation. I am trying to implement a store locator kind of function.

I am thinking to calculate minimum latitude and longitude for a given geocode and distance. Lets say I have lat: 41.850, lng: -87.650 and distance of 10 miles. is it possible to calculate all possible lat and longitude? and from the resulting values i will find the minimum and maximum lat & long. 
I am using oracle 11g DB and Java/JavaScript

Comment: Can you be more specific about the store location function?  What are the parameters of "storeLocatorFunction" and what does it return?  

My guess would be that you want to take a lat/lng and find the closest store correct?

Comment: All possible latitudes or longitudes are both nonsense

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use some `kdtree`.  The idea is that you insert your points into a kdtree, and then query it based on some distance from a known point.

If your data is stored in Oracle, then use Oracle's built in spatial capabilities which should offer a radius based search on top of a point geometry type: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_intro.htm#i880253

If you implementing in JavaScript, I would first check out https://github.com/ubilabs/kd-tree-javascript and their example: http://ubilabs.github.io/kd-tree-javascript/examples/map/